# Why is serializable needed in ticket booking?

Tags: database, postgresql, isolation-level

In this article
[https://kkyr.io/blog/serializability-vs-linearizability/#:~:text=Banking%20example&text=The%20banking%20system%20uses%20a,and%20does%20not%20guarantee%20linearizability](https://kkyr.io/blog/serializability-vs-linearizability/#:%7E:text=Banking%20example&text=The%20banking%20system%20uses%20a,and%20does%20not%20guarantee%20linearizability).

The author explains that serializable isolation level is needed to avoid the following scenario

```
time 1 Alice start transaction select ticket_avail from concert where id = 1
time 2 Bob start transaction select ticket_avail from concert where id = 1
time 3 Alice update concert set ticket_avail = ticket_avail - 1 where id = 1
time 4 Bob update concert set ticket_avail = ticket_avail - 1 where id = 1
```

This is a race condition if there is only one ticket, so isolation level of serializable is needed

But isolation level only applies to select, all update auto locks the row and examine the latest committed value

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html

So the following will work

```
time 1 Alice start transaction 
select ticket_avail from concert where id = 1
time 2 Bob start transaction 
select ticket_avail from concert where id = 1 
time 3 Alice 
update concert set ticket_avail = ticket_avail - 1 where id = 1 and ticket_avail > 0
time 4 Bob 
update concert set ticket_avail = ticket_avail - 1 where id = 1 and ticket_avail > 0
```

Alice will get the last ticket and bob will not get the last ticket because the where clause is reevaluated in update

Is serializable isolation really needed in this example?

Comment: Your example makes no sense.  Alice is trying to buy two tickets and Bob zero?

Comment: sorry, copy pasta, the question is fixed.

Comment: You can always work around things.  The work-arounds might get increasingly unpleasant as cases get more complex, until you would rather have the database engine do it for you.  In your last example, why have the selects at all?  The updates update, or they don't.  What is there to select?